# Apache proxypass does not resolve url for resources like images and css

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy, proxypass

I need to map a path to my tomcat web application. I used proxypass for this.
this is the current config in apache2

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName localhost:80
        ProxyPass /app http://localhost:8088/ui/
        ProxyPassReverse /app http://localhost:8088/ui/


        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

This gets the HTML from tomcat but the css url formed is wrong. Instead of `http://localhost/app/css/style.css`the url is mapped as `http://localhost/ui/css/style.css`.

I tried using rewrite but it did not work.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/ui/ /app/
```

I need to find the right way to correct the URL.
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, I found two different solution to my problem.

1. Using mod_rewrite and some changes to proxypass:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       ProxyPreserveHost On
       ProxyPass /app http://localhost:8080/ui/
       ProxyPassReverse /app http://localhost:8080/ui/

       #since in java web app the context started with /ui the js src had /ui in the beginning
       #this resulted in 404 so I had to rewrite all request to /ui to forward to /app

       RewriteEngine on
       RewriteRule    "^/ui(.+)"  "/app$1"  [R,L]

       ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
       CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
2. Create a link/shorcut to deployed application inside webapp folder and name the shorcut as app
   In linux the command is(from inside webapp folder) `ln -s ui app`

Now the apache config is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ProxyPreserveHost On

        <Location /app>
            ProxyPass  ajp://localhost:8019/app/
            ProxyPassReverse ajp://localhost:8019/app/
            SetOutputFilter  proxy-html
            ProxyHTMLExtended On
            ProxyHTMLURLMap /app /app
            RequestHeader    unset  Accept-Encoding
        </Location>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

In the first solution the rewrite mod causes request to return 304 before redirecting to correct url. That is how it works by default.

In the second solution since both handlers are same(/app) there is no reason for redirection and the URL's are mapped correctly.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on what you want the displayed URL to be. If you want it to be

http://localhost/app/

Then you need to move your static content under /ui/ in your WAR.

If you want

http://localhost/app/ui

Then you should remove the trailing /ui from your ProxyPass lines

As a third option, you could create a 'ROOT' symlink to 'ui' in your tomcat webapp directory (and remove /ui from the proxy), which would allow you to serve your app from the root of the tomcat path

Comment: /ui is the context path for the webapp. removing that will point /app to tomcats base /

Comment: Yes, so then when you make a request to http://localhost/app/ui it will go to the correct location. You haven't said what you actually want in your URL.

Comment: I want localhost/app to be mapped to localhost:8088/ui. Request to localhost/app/ui will not work because /ui is already mapped to /app . I am able to get the html of /ui but the css are all relative url that starts with /ui. So i need to find a way to address this issue.

Comment: OK, you still didn't say what you actually want to see in your URL. I can't help you until you say that. Do you want to *see* the /ui/ or not? I can take a guess, and say that you should do the second of my suggestions, and add a ROOT symlink to tomcat.

Comment: No i don't want /ui in my url. I want every url to be mapped to /app including the js and css.

Comment: OK, so did you do what I said?