# Modify URL of a dockerized shiny app and remove port number

Tags: r, docker, apache, shiny

I have a dockerized Shiny app working fine on my server. I exposed it on port 2007 and is available at this url :

```
http://myshinyserver.com:2007
```

I would like to "give" a name at this app by modifying the url and hide the port number as this :

```
http://myshinyserver.com/my_app
```

I modify my apache conf by adding this section :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName myshinyserver.com
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass /my_app http://0.0.0.0:2007
ProxyPassReverse /my_app http://0.0.0.0:2007
</VirtualHost>
```

It works but with a big failure !

There is no background colors, none image displayed, just some links instead of tabs as if it was no template. No select input, no textarea input are visible, my plots doesn't appears...

So it works without server error but the content of my app is full of issues.

Any clue ?

Thanx !

Edit :

This solution [Apache proxypass does not resolve url for resources like images and css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40340024/apache-proxypass-does-not-resolve-url-for-resources-like-images-and-css) don't works because i don't have the ui part of this rule :

```
RewriteRule    "^/ui(.+)"  "/app$1"  [R,L]
```

I tried to remove ui as this but the resulting url is not conform :

```
RewriteRule    "^/(.+)"  "/app$1"  [R,L]
```

And I'm unable to create a link/shorcut because the app is in a docker

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache proxypass does not resolve url for resources like images and css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40340024/apache-proxypass-does-not-resolve-url-for-resources-like-images-and-css)

Comment: @Pino it doesn't work, see my edit in my post

Comment: You say "I don't have the UI part of this rule" but where are the missing resources located in your app? Which URLs give 404? Your question does not contain enough information. It seems that you are applying that solution in the wrong way.

Comment: @Pino in the previous example, ui is not the ui part of the shiny app, ui is a part of the url